# My Google Maps fragment displays gray. I can't get the actual map to appear

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a Google Maps fragment to a Tabbed Layout, but the maps only display as a gray fragment with the Google logo in the bottom left-hand corner. My API key is valid and I have enabled the API and SDK through Google Cloud Platform.

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private View mView;
    MapView mapView;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mapView = getView().findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.onResume();

        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if(mapView != null) {
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        mMap = map;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    }
```

fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyC-MdT7T9uXkL0GmpbsMeWJsBwhorqAc3c"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="603dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[Screenshot of my app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuLit.png)

**SOLUTION**
Many times the error is with the credentials. I had re-made the credentials and the error persisted, despite having all necessary APIs enabled in Google Cloud. The error was instead that the original credentials were preserved in the app on the emulator despite changing the API key. On the emulator (or device), go to `Settings>Application Manager>Select Your Application > Click on Clear Data`.

Another solution is to completely uninstall the application and reload it after re-making credentials.

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked many times. Nine times out of ten, it is invalid key. Delete you key and generate a new one.

Comment: If it's been asked many times then you should flag it as a duplicate and link it to a case where it's been asked and answered.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION**

Many times the error is with the credentials. I had re-made the credentials and the error persisted, despite having all necessary APIs enabled in Google Cloud. The error was instead that the original credentials were preserved in the app on the emulator despite changing the API key. On the emulator (or device), go to Settings>Application Manager>Select Your Application > Click on Clear Data.

Another solution is to completely uninstall the application and reload it after re-making credentials.